# finding limits algebraically as x tends to 2 or infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I saw the following example of finding limits algebraically in a math text book(Pure mathematics)by J.K Backhouse and S.P.Houldsworth
f(x)=(2x)/(1+x)
***example 1***  if we put in values of x as they tend to 2 in the above function we see that f(x) tends to twelve
The author divides the numerator and the denominator by x giving us
f(x)=(2)/((1)/(x)+1)
in the above function he lets x tend to infinity and we see that f(x) tends to 2

***example 2***
f(X)=(x^3-8)/(x-2) as x tends to 2 f(x) tends to 12
Here's the confusing part the author in the example says let x be 2+h
leading to
=12+6h+h^2
he lets h tend to 0 and in doing so f(x) tends to 12 somehow
I am finding it really difficult to understand the above examples

Comment: For example $1$: As $x$ approaches infinity, what can be said about $1/x$? For example $2$: As $h$ approaches $0$, what can be said about $6h$? And what about $h^2$?

Comment: 1/x tends to zero and 6h tends to 0

Comment: So if you add things that tend to zero to other things, then . . .

Comment: you find there limits but how do you arrive to 12+6h+h^2 and 2/(1/x)+1)

Comment: For example $1$: Divide numerator and denominator by $x$, then distribute the division for the top and bottom separately. For example $2$: Substitute $2 +  h$ for $x$. Then expand, factor, and simplify. Note: When we take the limit as $h$ approaches $0$, we don't let $h$ be actually _equal_ to zero. This allows the cancellation $h/h = 1$.

Comment: For example $1$: Do you agree that $2/((1/x) + 1)$ approaches $2/(0 +1) = 2/1 = 2$, as $x$ approaches infinity? For example $2$: Do you agree that $12 + 6h + h^2$ approaches $12 + 0 + 0 = 12$, as $h$ approaches $0$?

Comment: @Gonja `how do you arrive to 12+6h+h^2` Do you know the [binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)? Just expand $\,(2+h)^3\,$, then note that the first term $\,2^3=8\,$ cancels out with the $\,-8\,$ that follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **example 1**, after dividing numerator and denominator by $x$ you have $$\frac{2}{\frac1x+1}$$  And since as $x$ tends to infinity $\frac1x$ tends to $0$, you can see $\frac{2}{\frac1x+1}$ tends to $\frac{2}{0+1} = 2$. In **example 2**, where $$f(x)= \frac{x^3-8}{x-2}$$you are looking for lim$f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $2$. But letting $x=2$ only gives $\frac00$. So we let $x$ = $2+h$ and watch what happens as $h$ tends to $0$. Substituting $2+h$ for $x$ gives$$\frac{(2+h)^3-8}{(2+h)-2}=\frac{12h+6h^2+h^3}{h} = 12+6h+h^2$$  And since as $h$ goes to $0$, $6h$ and $h^2$, and hence also their sum, goes to $0$, therefore $12+6h+h^2$ tends to $12$ as $h$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful